# How to merge two Data Frames based on a few columns in second Data Frame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two Pandas Data Frame in Python like below:

df1

```
ID
----
11
22
33
44
```

df2

```
ID1   ID2   ID3
--------------------
11  | 5   | 114
88  | 22  | 18
99  | 45  | 33
```

- df1 has more rows than df2
- types of values in boths Data Frames is int

I need to do something like df1 LEFT JOIN df2 and merge df1 with df2 using "ID" from df1 and "ID1", "ID2", "ID3" from df2

1. merge Data Frames on ID (df1) and ID1 (df2)
2. if ID does not merge with ID1 --> merge on ID and ID2
3. if ID does not merge with ID2 --> merge on ID and ID3
4. give 123456 if rows does not merge

So as a result I need something like below:

```
ID    ID1   ID2   ID3
--------------------------
11  | 11     | 5       | 114
22  | 88     | 22      | 18
33  | 99     | 45      | 33
44  | 123456 | 123456  | 123456
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ? I totally do not know.

Comment: What is the expected result if ID=0 on your first dataframe?

Comment: Does ID is unique in your first dataframe?

Comment: Yes, ID is unique in df1

Comment: And for multiple match like 0?

Comment: Task is like: merge df with df2 by ID = ID1, but it does not merge make ID = ID2, but it does not merge make ID = ID3, but if ID does merge with any ID1, ID2, ID3 write 123456, it is not possible to have 0 it any of df1 or df2, I changed it in question :)

Comment: Corralien, is it clear for you now ? :)

Comment: Yes it's clear. I think I have a solution for you

Comment: Great, because I totally do not have idea :)

Comment: Corralien, may I ask how it's going? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stack `df2` to becomes `df2a`, then left join `df1` with `df2a` followed by left join original `df2` matching the original index.  Fill `NaN` with `123456` and drop intermediate columns to arrive at the desired output:

```
df2a = df2.stack().reset_index(name='ID')

df_out = (df1.merge(df2a, on='ID', how='left')
             .merge(df2, left_on='level_0', right_index=True, how='left')
             .fillna(123456, downcast='infer')
             .drop(['level_0', 'level_1'], axis=1)
         )
```

or simplify the second `.merge` with `.join` (thanks for the suggestion of @HenryEcker), as follows:

```
df2a = df2.stack().reset_index(name='ID')

df_out = (df1.merge(df2a, on='ID', how='left')
             .join(df2, on='level_0')
             .fillna(123456, downcast='infer')
             .drop(['level_0', 'level_1'], axis=1)
         )
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

   ID     ID1     ID2     ID3
0  11      11       5     114
1  22      88      22      18
2  33      99      45      33
3  44  123456  123456  123456
```

---

**Break down of step:**

```
print(df2a)

   level_0 level_1   ID
0        0     ID1   11
1        0     ID2    5
2        0     ID3  114
3        1     ID1   88
4        1     ID2   22
5        1     ID3   18
6        2     ID1   99
7        2     ID2   45
8        2     ID3   33
```

Comment: Seabean the first line should be: df1a = df1.stack().reset_index(name='ID') ? because in df2 there is no ID in df2 is ID1, ID2, ID3 in df1 is ID ?

Comment: @Matop  The first line is correct.  `ID` is created as an aggregation of `ID1`, `ID2`, `ID3`.  You can print the result of `df2a` and see it.

Comment: @Matop  I have included the result of `df2a` for your reference.

Comment: Wow, perfect, it works! I gave you best answer! thank you SeanBean :)

Comment: `.join(df2, on='level_0')` is equivalent to `.merge(df2, left_on='level_0', right_index=True, how='left')` and avoids some of the overhead of merge having to find the `join` command internally through arg parsing.

Comment: @HenryEcker  Good suggestion.  Thanks!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look here (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html), you have many different soutions. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
        "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
        "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],
    }
)


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["A4", "A5", "A6", "A7"],
        "B": ["B4", "B5", "B6", "B7"],
        "C": ["C4", "C5", "C6", "C7"],
        "D": ["D4", "D5", "D6", "D7"],
    }
)


df3 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "A": ["A8", "A9", "A10", "A11", "A12"],
    "B": ["B8", "B9", "B10", "B11", "B12"],
    "C": ["C8", "C9", "C10", "C11", "C12"],
    "D": ["D8", "D9", "D10", "D11", "D12"],
}
)
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)
```

Gives you:

```
     A    B    C    D    A    B    C    D    A    B    C    D
0   A0   B0   C0   D0   A4   B4   C4   D4   A8   B8   C8   D8
1   A1   B1   C1   D1   A5   B5   C5   D5   A9   B9   C9   D9
2   A2   B2   C2   D2   A6   B6   C6   D6  A10  B10  C10  D10
3   A3   B3   C3   D3   A7   B7   C7   D7  A11  B11  C11  D11
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  A12  B12  C12  D12
```

So, in your case:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [11, 22, 33, 44]
    }
)


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID1": [11, 88, 99],
        "ID2": [5, 22, 45],
        "ID3": [114, 18, 33]
    }
)


df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df.fillna('123456', inplace=True) # to replace NaNs with the values you want
```

Gives:

```
   ID     ID1     ID2     ID3
0  11    11.0     5.0   114.0
1  22    88.0    22.0    18.0
2  33    99.0    45.0    33.0
3  44  123456  123456  123456
```

Comment: For me it is not easy, could you present one possible solution ? The simplest in your opinion ? :)

Comment: Alessandro Peca, could you present this solution using my sample df1 and df2 ?

Comment: Updated. Please flag it as the correct answer if it works for you.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this only works in this specific instance because df2 is already in the correct order. If you shuffle the rows in df2 this approach no longer works.